How can I add a vertical divider in ListItem?
How can I add a vertical divider between headlineContent and trailingContent in ListItem() with Jetpack Compose that looks like this:


With material3, you should use a VerticalDivider:
import androidx.compose.material3.VerticalDivider

@Composable
fun SettingsRow() {
    var checked by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Wireless debugging", style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall)
            Text(text = "Debug mode when Wi-Fi is connected")
        }
        VerticalDivider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
        )
        Switch(
            checked = checked,
            onCheckedChange = {
                checked = it
            }
        )
    }
}

Output:


If you are using Material Design 2, you can make the Divider vertical as follows:
Divider(
    color = Color.Black,
    modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp).width(1.dp)
)

If you want to make the Divider fill the whole height of the Row instead of the fixed height of 32.dp, use
Row(
    modifier = modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {

    // Texts ...
    Divider(
        color = Color.Black,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().width(1.dp)
    )
    // Switch ...
}


I think what you're looking for is a Divider
I'm not sure what ListItem is but I'll attempt to recreate the view from your image using Jetpack Compose
This item could be recreated using the following
@Composable
fun ItemRowWithSwitch(enabled: Boolean = false, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
   var checked by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(enabled) }
   Row(
      modifier = modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
   ) {
      Column {
         Text(text = "Wireless debugging")
         Text(text = "Debug mode when Wi-Fi is connected")
      }
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
      Divider()
      Switch(
         checked = checked,
         onCheckedChange = {
            checked = it
         }
      )
   }
}


The problem is that Divider() is only horizontal

i theres a workaround that includes set height to fillMaxSize, but it expands the listItem to fill the whole screen

use any Box composable with height to fillParent and width 1.dp
